# libgdx lag when sound.play() while collecting apple

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

I'am doing simple libgdx game. I have lag (game stop for 0. 5 sec) when i use sound.play() 
**edit** this bug apear on android 4.0 on 2.3 everything is running fine.

method. I play sound by this code:

```
if(CollisionDetector.detect(touchArea, hoodie.getTouchArea())){
        GameScreen.totalScore++;
        setPosition();
        System.out.println("played");

        Assets.eatSound.play();

}
```

And i use this method to load sound:

```
 static long waitForLoadCompleted(Sound sound,float volume) {
        long id;
        while ((id = sound.play(volume)) == -1) {
            long t = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
            while (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - t < 100000000);
        }
        return id;
 }
```

What am i doing wrong? Or what can i do to fix this lag ?

**edit:**

I have just tried to do thread with sound.play() but it also doesn't work:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              // do something important here, asynchronously to the rendering thread

              // post a Runnable to the rendering thread that processes the result
              Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    // process the result, e.g. add it to an Array<Result> field of the ApplicationListener.
                eatSound2.play();
                 }
              });
           }
        }).start();
```

My Sound asset class looks like this but i still have lag with sound.
package com.redHoodie;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable;

public class SoundEffect implements Disposable {
   private static final int WaitLimit = 1000;
   private static final int ThrottleMs = 100;
    Sound eatSound;
    Sound endSound;

    public SoundEffect(){
        eatSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("eatSound.ogg"));
        endSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sadend.wav"));

        checkedPlay(eatSound);
    }

   protected long checkedPlay (Sound sound) {
      return checkedPlay(sound, 1);
   }

   protected long checkedLoop (Sound sound) {
      return checkedLoop(sound, 1);
   }

   protected long checkedPlay (Sound sound, float volume) {
      int waitCounter = 0;
      long soundId = 0;

      boolean ready = false;
      while (!ready && waitCounter < WaitLimit) {
         soundId = sound.play(volume);
         ready = (soundId != 0);
         waitCounter++;
         try {
            Thread.sleep(ThrottleMs);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
      }

      return soundId;
   }

   protected long checkedLoop (Sound sound, float volume) {
      int waitCounter = 0;
      long soundId = 0;

      boolean ready = false;
      while (!ready && waitCounter < WaitLimit) {
         soundId = sound.loop(volume);
         ready = (soundId != 0);
         waitCounter++;
         try {
            Thread.sleep(ThrottleMs);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
      }

      return soundId;
   }

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Is this possible that i have this lags cause my sound variables are static ?

Comment: What does your Assets class look like? Are you by any chance re-loading the sound every time you want to play it? I don't understand your `waitForLoadCompleted` method--are you doing some kind of asynchronous loading?

Comment: I load my sounds only once in constructor of my GameScreen. I found in the internet that playing sound with 0 volume may help to load this sound, thats why i use waitForLoadCompleted.

Comment: in logCat i get information that "sample 5 not Ready"

Comment: But where are you calling `waitForLoadCompleted`, right after loading the sound the only time?

Comment: I call this one time after i create  SoundEffect class where i have my sounds.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. It was because my .mp3 file was too short. Mine was 0.167 seconds long. I added 1.2 seconds of silence with Audacity, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: With more sounds my game started lagging even more. Tried adding 1 second of silence to each sound sample, but didn't help. :( On PC runs smooth, but on phone (SD 855, 6GB ram, android 10) it lags.  LibGDX definitely has some sound issue. :(

Comment: Initially I used 22Khz wav pcm samples to save the memory. But then tried 44100, 48000Hz, tried adding them second of silence at end. Nothing helps. I would say that just LibGDX (or Android even) sound system is not good enough and can't handle nearly the same number of samples at the same time as PC. Only solution I see is reducing number of sounds played unfortunatelly.

Comment: I also tried everything from changing the bitrate, and using different file extensions such as wav, mp3, flac, but unfortunately that didn't help. Your solution helped me fix the problem after months of searching. I think the important part is to turn the volume down in the file itself and yes you may therefore have to also lengthen the sample (I used Ableton live) . The only physical phone I could to test on was a motorola g5 plus. It may be because this phone keeps the audio stream or thread or something open. Thanks a thousand, this should be upvoted for others to find more easily.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still facing this issue as me there is the alternative solution with one limitation: no option to use sound id.

You can change default LibGDX behavior and use `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` by overriding this method in your `AndroidLauncher` class:

```
@Override
public AndroidAudio createAudio(Context context, AndroidApplicationConfiguration config) {
    return new AsynchronousAndroidAudio(context, config);
}
```

See the [official documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Audio) for more info and also [the pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/6243)

Also, if for any reasons you need sound id you can take this implementation as an example and find a workaround for your project.

Fix is available starting from LibGDX 1.9.12

Comment: Great solution! Works perfectly. You save a lot of time for me. Thanks! Looks like should be selected.

Comment: In this case game not glitching but the sound doesn't play properly.

Comment: I quickly moved to [libgdx mini audio](https://github.com/rednblackgames/gdx-miniaudio) and it solved almost all my issues related to sound playing.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I run into the same issue (except I'm using wav instead mp3 files). My app was lagging when I play many (like 10 or 20) sounds at the same time (same render method). "Solved" this by playing only 1 sound at the time. Generally it's hard to distinct many sounds at the same time. Also on desktop it works fine, but problem appears on android (9 or 8).

Comment: A little bit late but try extending your samples and turn the volume down before the end of the sample. I have Ableton Live but you could probably also use Audacity, which is free.

Comment: Tried that too. I don't need that there's any help for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022221/sound-makes-app-lags-on-android-any-solution

Comment: I made a bit smarter sound manager system, set some kind of priorities for sounds and I'm playing just 2 or 3 sounds at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I was occurred the same problem when I trying to make a rhythm game and I wanted to play some effect sounds. Thus I tried `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` to solved it. However `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` seemed to cause more problems like sound latency. And finally I used OpenSL ES and it worked well in improving performance (on my poor device produced in 2016). But I just wrote few functions and what's worse is that all sound file should be converted to PCM format unless import a decoder. It met my need though (these sounds are small so that I loaded them directly into memory and these sounds do not need ID, even pausing)
(My English is not so well)